# Difference in Activity and Context and methods of getting them

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi am totally confused can some please explain the difference between these methods of getting context and activity:

```
public static final void onResume(Context context, MBase mem) {
     function.start(id, context);
}
public static final void onResume(Context context, MBase mem) {
     function.start(id, (Activity) context);
}
public static final void onResume(Activity activity, MBase mem) {
     function.start(id, activity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understand: [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is the Base Object. So every [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) same as [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) derives from Context. This means that every Activity and every Application IS a Context;

So for Generalised call you can use Context and for call from Activity Specially you can use Activity only .

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I thought that but only the 2nd and 3rd one work when using it in reference to a 3rd party ad provider and the suggestions from ADT are change type of context to activity

Comment: ok , its just because that will need only activity reference .
Means that 3rd party ad provider method will be only accepting Activity object so . And it can take context object but its type should be converted to Activity

Answer (score 1):

Activity extends from Context.

> java.lang.Object    ↳ android.content.Context
>        ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
>            ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
>                ↳    android.app.Activity

(Activity) context is type casting. Context is the base Class. It's like car (Activity) is a kind of vehicle (Context), but vehicle is not definitely a car.

Answer (score 0):

Context is a super-class of Activity - and also of amongst others Service and Application. This means casting a Context (second example) may be unsafe if you're giving it a non-Activity Context.

You should really look into an object-oriented approach either way - using static methods are normally not a great design. Instead, in your activity you can have the following method instead of the static onResume():

```
public void startFunction(Function function, MBase mem) {
   function.start(id, this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the oop approach, will look into this also